# matlab length of each element in cell array

Tags: matlab

```
a={'a','aa','aaa','aaaa'}
length(a)
  4
size(a)
  1 4
```

How can I get the length of each element in the cell array with a **single command**? The desired output in the above example would be `[1 2 3 4]`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
cellfun('length',a)
```

"apply `length(x)` to each element `x` in `a`".

[`cellfun` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html).

Comment: More 'modern' usage is to supply a function handle as the first argument, i.e. `cellfun(@length, a)`.

Answer (score 0):

arrayfun - Apply function to each element of array
check documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html

Comment: Are you really sure about ARRAYFUN in this case? You'd have to go through some contortions, i.e. `arrayfun( @(c) length(c{1}), a)` rather than the much simpler, and more obvious `cellfun(@length, a)`