# MATLAB: Delete elements in cell array with certain length

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

how can I delete all elements of a cell array that have less then for example 5 elements inside.

```
result{1}= 1
result{2}= [2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
result{3}= [9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18]
result{4}= [19 20 21]
```

In this example I want to delete `result{1}` and `result{4}`, because they have less than 5 elements inside.

With this topic ( [matlab length of each element in cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060321/matlab-length-of-each-element-in-cell-array)) I know how to get the length of each element, but how is possible to delete elements of a specific length?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just choose the ones that have more than 4 elements by logical indexing:

```
result = result(cellfun('length', result) >= 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you need. But the above answer from Mohsen is very compact and nice.

```
result{1}= 1;
result{2}= {2 3 4 5 6 7 8};
result{3}= {9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18};
result{4}= {19 20 21};

i = 1;
while i<=size(result,2)
    if size(result{i},2)<5
        result(i)=[];
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```

Comment: It matters not very much in matlab, but a for loop would look much nicer here. Though you cannot limit the lifetime of loop variables as good as in some other languages, it at least gives an indication that I would not be used outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: @patrik, But can I decrement my index variable i inside a for loop in Matlab?

Comment: You do not really need that since in a for loop you do `for ( i = 1:size(result,2) )`